# How do I loop through Vimeo API with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, vimeo-api

How can I loop through this array and display all the titles for the videos?

The result of {{dd($films)}}

```
array:3 [▼
  "body" => array:5 [▼
    "total" => 597
    "page" => 1
    "per_page" => 10
    "paging" => array:4 [▶]
    "data" => array:10 [▼
      0 => array:30 [▼
        "uri" => "/videos/280174677"
        "name" => "_DLA P_4093_GPC_French Lunchtime Partners film_180716_BN"
        "description" => null
        "link" => "https://vimeo.com/280174677"
        "transcode" => array:1 [▶]
      ]
      1 => array:30 [▶]
      2 => array:30 [▶]
      3 => array:30 [▶]
      4 => array:30 [▶]
      5 => array:30 [▶]
```

Comment: You need to loop on the data, not on the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
@foreach ($films['data'] as $film) 
      {{ $film['name'] }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: This returned Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @KlausAndrade in your answer result from `dd($film)` or `dd($films)` ?

Comment: The initial value is $films